# How do you differentiate "MOV r/m64, imm32" vs "MOV r/m32, imm32" in MASM64?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, masm, masm64

The Intel manual says `mov` has two variants involving both memory and 32-bit immediate operands:

```
MOV r/m32, imm32
MOV r/m64, imm32
```

The first one copies four bytes, the second copies eight, taking the given 32-bit immediate and sign-extending it to 64 bits.

How do you specify which one you want when writing assembly code for MASM64?

Comment: Presumably by specifying an `r` (register) that is 32-bits (like `eax`) or 64-bits (like `rax`), or an `m` (memory operand) with `dword ptr` or `qword ptr` (or, in MASM, specify a variable of the desired size).

Comment: Ah, interesting, I was trying to differentiate the second operand but differentiating the first does the right thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@ecm's comment above gives the answer:

```
mov qword ptr [rsp+08h], 0   ; selects MOV r/m64, imm32
mov dword ptr [rsp+08h], 0   ; selects MOV r/m32, imm32
```

Answer (score 2):

Override the size of the memory operand, like always.

```
mov   qword ptr [rdx], 123
add   byte ptr [rcx], 1
movzx eax,  word ptr [r8]
shl   dword ptr [r9], cl
```

**It makes sense in general to think about setting the size of the memory operand, not the immediate**, because that always works, even with `movzx` or `shl dword ptr [mem], 4` where the operands don't have to be the same size (the shift count is a byte and could be CL).

You're not overriding anything about the immediate; you still want `add qword ptr [mem], 4` to use a sign_extended_imm8 encoding, leaving the encoding up to the assembler.  (Only `mov` and `test` lack sign-extended byte forms, out of ALU instructions that come from original 8086.)

---

Even for assemblers like NASM that do accept `add [rcx], word 0x0001`, I'd never write it that way.

Especially in NASM where you can force it to use a 4-byte immediate with `add qword [rdi], strict qword 123` which would use a 4-byte immediate in the machine code that something else could rewrite. Using `dword` on an immediate without `strict` seems like the wrong way of thinking about it.

Especially with NASM's default optimization enabled so you don't need stuff like `mov rax, dword -1` to avoid the imm64 encoding, or `add dword [rdi], byte 1` to avoid the imm32 encoding.  (With `nasm -O0`, those *do* pick longer encodings if you didn't suggest the smaller encoding with a non-strict hint, so putting sizes on immediates is something you can do separately from setting the *operand*-size.)

(NASM's a bit messy in requiring `strict qword 123` for `add qword [rdi], strict qword 123`, not `strict dword`, matching the operand-size instead of the immediate width.  IMO it's a bug that it rejects `add qword [rdi], strict dword 123`.  Probably the syntax was designed before x86-64 existed, and/or design mistakes were made in how to extend it to cases where there are non-full-width immediates other than bytes.)